# How to reinstall HP BIOS

Tags: installation, bios, reinstall, hp-pavilion

I am dual booting my PC with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. Both are working. I have no problem. Today I started seeing this error:

```
The HP Bios application selected is corrupt or missing. 
Please install the application and try again.
Install BIOS application error 501
Enter - continue
For more information please visit http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01442956
```

How to fix BIOS?

Comment: _Where_ do you see the error?

Comment: @terdon i saw it when i turned on my laptop, and when i restarted ubuntu, but now it disappeared! maybe i should ignore it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this thread](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-HP-ProBook-EliteBook/HP-6730b-quot-BIOS-Application-error-501-quot/td-p/1075640), I would guess that you removed the EFI partition when installing your Linux system. You can safely ignore the message and suppress it by disabling 'HP Quicklook' from the BIOS setup.

This is the relevant information from the linked thread:

> This is a feature. You are using info-button to start and have no
>   efi-partition (HP_Tools) installed.
>
> Disable 'HP Quicklook' from bios setup.
>
> ---
>
> HP EliteBook Notebook PC Series - BIOS Application Error (501)
>
> Information
>
> You may have get a 'BIOS Application Error 501' error message if using
>   not HP Preload image and press INFO button when starting unit. The HP
>   BIOS application selected is corrupt or missing. Please install the
>   application and try again.
>
> BIOS Application Error (501)
>
> Enter - Continue
>
> Details This error is the result of using the INFO button launch HP
>   EFI Application and if not using HP Preload image, the operating
>   system cannot find the EFI partition.
>
> What is EFI ? EFI is a set modular interfaces that replaced the set of
>   traditional BIOS interfaces between the OS and platform firmware. The
>   EFI partition is viewable on HP Preload image and HDD and is labeled
>   as HP_TOOLS. The EFI partition and HP EFI application are not required
>   for the basic operation of HP Notebook, however, if partition is
>   missing, EFI feature is not available.
>
> Read mode on EFI Features on the "HP Business Notebook Computer - EFI
>   Guidelines" that are downloadable on the www.hp.com
>
> EFI Guidelines (116.5KB, PDF) HP Business Notebook Computer
>   http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01564727/c01564727.pdf?jumpid=reg_R1002_USE...
>
> Pekka

Comment: you're right, i don't see it anymore, maybe i should ignore it as you said, i don't see it anymore

Answer (score 0):

One of my users experienced this error. Our system builds remove the partition that the HP BIOS is searching for, your partitioning for dual boot could have similarly removed or changed the HP_Tools partition (I think that's the label of the parition their laptops ship with, uncertain).

The softpaq article that HP hosts as a solution to error 501 I that I found suggests flashing the bios. In my case it was sp62738, correpsonds with Elitebooks 8460p/w and 8560p as well as Probooks 6360b, 6460b, 6560b.
This was not however the solution. **In every case I found that disabling the 'HP Quicklook' in the BIOS remedies the error on all of the machines that showed this error**, all of them were EB8460p or 8560p models.

Quicklook appears to be a caching service for MS Outlook. Users who are aware of the feature can use it to rapidly access a pre-boot environment that hosts a copy of their emails/calendar/tasks/etc. Having never used it and forcing it disabled to allow my corporate users functionality of their laptops means I can't really speak on it's use but it's deployment certainly leaves something to be desired.